# Как передать данные с одного класса в другой с помощью делегатов(WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события, делегаты

У меня есть 2 ViewModela, "A" и "B". "А" создаёт "B". После чего все операции я выполняю в "B"(Произвожу некоторые изменения данных на его View). И я хочу чтобы при нажатии на одну из кнопок данные из "B" попали в "A".Подскажите, как правильно это сделать.

Comment: `... CommandParameter = "{Binding SomeValue}"`?

Comment: Из дочерней вьюмодели уведомить родительскую? Куча вариантов - классические события (главное подумать про отписку), слабые события, подписка на INPC дочерней, функция обратного вызова ака калбэк, мессенджер (в каждом MVVM фрймворке есть). Тут кому что нравится. Некоторые передают родительскую в дочернюю как прямую ссылку даже - но я считаю это неправильным.